# How do i cast a string type to a class type ? here is the ERROR MESSAGE:- Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'query'

Tags: c#, .net

How do i cast a sting type to another type?
i have tried different options but when i run the application it throws an error message
//first code

```
       public static Xxl.Query QueryBySize(string SizeNo)
        {
            Query result = new Query();
            result.SizeInfo.SizeCode = "Xxl";
            Xxl.Query result1 = new Xxl.Query()
            {
                SIZE = SizeNo
            };
          
            JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                IgnoreNullValues = true
            };
            string str = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Xxl.Query>(result1, options);
            Console.WriteLine("Retrieved Details: " + str);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
            result.Data.Content = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            Xxl.Query xxl = (Xxl.Query)QueryRequest(result );

            return xxl;
        }
//second code from another file Name:  Xxl.cs
```

```
   public class Query
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("itemName")]
        public ItemName ItemName { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("result")]
        public string Result { get; set; }

        public Query()
        {
            ItemName = new ItemName();
        }
    }
```

How do i go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i cast a sting type to another type?

You don't.  Because a `string` and a `Query` are fundamentally different things.  But you can *construct* a `Query` using a `string` for its one `string` property.  For example:

```
new Query { Result = someString }
```

This is something you *already do* on the third line of your method.  (Though apparently with a different `Query`?)  Just repeat that same logic any time you want to build a `Query` using a `string`.

Comment: Hello, i tried the above suggestion but it didn't help. Any other recommendation?

Comment: @karcs: What "didn't help" about it?  What is your updated code and in what specific way does it fail?  If what you want is to create an instance of your `Query` object then, no, there is no "other recommendation" than to create an instance of your `Query` object.

Comment: I got it solved. it turns out there was nothing wrong with my code. The issue was with one of the dependencies of the System.text.json.dll library called system.numeric.vectors.dll ,once i added it to the project i stopped getting the exception. Thanks for the effort